# Converting IN and UNION to something more efficient ( Probably EXISTS)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM   sec 
WHERE  sec.cu IN (SELECT s.cu 
                  FROM   sec s WITH (nolock) 
                  WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
                                 FROM   hact h WITH ( nolock), 
                                 JOIN   dport p WITH ( nolock) ON h.ic = p.ic
                                 WHERE  s.cu = h.cu )

                  UNION 
                  SELECT s.cu 
                  FROM   sec s WITH (nolock) 
                  WHERE  EXISTS(SELECT * 
                                FROM   schanges c WITH ( nolock) 
                                WHERE  s.cu = c.cu) 
                  UNION 
                  SELECT s.cu 
                  FROM   sec s WITH (nolock) 
                  WHERE  s.cu IN (SELECT DISTINCT cu 
                                  FROM   suk WITH (nolock))) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * 
                   FROM   hact h WITH (nolock) 
                          JOIN port p WITH (nolock) 
                            ON h.ic = p.ic 
                   WHERE  sec.cu = h.cu 
                          AND p.ptype = 'X')
```

Hi I have this query which i am trying to optimize. I have tries to convert it to remove unions and In to more readable but failed. I am trying to make it more efficient probably only using EXISTS and NOT EXISTS.

Comment: How long does the query within the IN clause take to execute?

Comment: What's with the `WITH (nolock)`? Why are you using it?

Comment: Query within IN take around 3-4 seconds but the IN clause overall slows down the query

Comment: Our database is very transaction heavy so we do not want our select query's to slow down our internal application. We dont mind dirty reads but we want faster application and no deadlocks

Comment: Add the tables' definitions (including indexes) and the execution plan of the query.

Comment: If the "database" is transaction-heavy (? do you mean write-heavy? read-heavy? or just generally busy?), then maybe you should consider optimizing the server for that specific workload. If you're experiencing that many deadlocks that's usually an indication of a flaw in the design. Additionally, the goal of query optimization is to improve performance *and* remove these sorts of kludgy workarounds.

Comment: You are right that's true. But we are improving slowly and steadily. The above query had implicit joins too :-) So this is ancient code base Hopefully we can make it out alive

Comment: As I stated in my answer: please provide the relevant Table, Key and Index definitions.  And most importantly, show us the query plan.  Otherwise, we are just guessing here.  (And if this is just a View definition and not an actual query, then make sure that you show the query plan for an actual query that uses the view (and has the performance issues).)

Comment: A select should not cause a deadlock as it is a read only operation.  A readlock will hold up any write operation and on a busy severs can cause an update to timeout but that is not a deadlock.  I use with (nolock) a lot and don't consider it a kluge.  If you are getting deadlocks then need to look at table design and the write transactions that are deadlocking.

Comment: @Blam this was my point, but wanted to encourage the OP to update with more details and think about the workload that their server was supporting. thank you for summarizing and including more information.

Comment: Hi Blam/Swascheck. I am sorry I dont have any more information about nolock and why it is encouraged and used a lot. I am not database expert but DB Team in the company recommends to use it. I am sure they are working towards solving latency/deadlock/readlock issues in the application using table partitioning and what not. Anyways thanks for your insight will bug the database guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified version that should be functionally equivalent:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM   sec s WITH (nolock) 
WHERE (
  EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM   hact h WITH ( nolock)
    JOIN   dport p WITH ( nolock) 
      ON h.ic = p.ic
    WHERE  s.cu = h.cu 
  ) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM   schanges c WITH ( nolock)
    WHERE  s.cu = c.cu
  ) OR EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM   suk WITH (nolock)
    WHERE  s.cu = suk.cu
  )
) AND EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
  FROM   hact h WITH (nolock) 
  JOIN port p WITH (nolock) 
    ON h.ic = p.ic 
  WHERE  
    s.cu = h.cu 
    AND p.ptype = 'X'
)
```

Comment: This works perfectly. I was almost there. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

I think that you can rewrite your nested in/exists in this way:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sec 
WHERE sec.cu IN (
  SELECT s.cu 
  FROM sec s 
  INNER JOIN hact h ON s.cu = h.cu, 
  INNER JOIN dport p ON h.ic = p.ic

  UNION ALL

  SELECT s.cu
  FROM sec s
  INNER JOIN schanges c ON s.cu = c.cu) 

  UNION ALL

  SELECT s.cu 
  FROM sec s 
  INNER JOIN suk k ON k.cu = s.cu
  INNER JOIN hact h ON s.cu = h.cu
  INNER JOIN port p ON h.ic = p.ic AND p.ptype = 'X'
)
```

Or even remove the `sec` table from the subqueries entirely:

```
SELECT * 
FROM sec 
WHERE sec.cu IN (
  SELECT h.cu 
  FROM hact h
  INNER JOIN dport p ON h.ic = p.ic

  UNION ALL

  SELECT cu
  FROM schanges

  UNION ALL

  SELECT k.cu 
  FROM suk k
  INNER JOIN hact h ON s.cu = h.cu
  INNER JOIN port p ON h.ic = p.ic AND p.ptype = 'X'
)
```

Comment: You both Queries return different result set than the original query. Slightly more rows

Answer (score 1):

Just change your UNION clauses to UNION ALL.  That alone should help some.

To be able to help you any more than that without us just blindly guessing, you are going to have to provide us with Table, Key and Index definitions, as well as the query plan.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but I think you can do this with joins

```
select distinct s.*
from   sec s with (nolock)
join   hatch h1 with (nolock)
  on   h1.cu = s.cu
       join  port p1 WITH (nolock) 
         ON  h1.ic = p1.ic
        AND  p1.ptype = 'X'
left join hact h2 WITH ( nolock)
  on   h2.cu = s.cu
       join  port p2 WITH (nolock) 
         ON  h2.ic = p2.ic
left join  schanges c WITH ( nolock) 
  on   s.cu = c.cu 
left join  suc WITH ( nolock) 
  on   s.cu = suc.cu 
where h2.cu  is not null
   or c.cu   is not null
   or suc.cu is not null
```

union intersect might be faster 
depends on how smart the query optimizer was

```
(   
    select s.*
    from   sec s with (nolock)
    join hact h2 WITH (nolock)
      on   h2.cu = s.cu
           join  port p2 WITH (nolock) 
             ON  h2.ic = p2.ic
  union
    select s.*
    from   sec s with (nolock)
    join  schanges c WITH ( nolock) 
      on   s.cu = c.cu 
  union
    select s.*
    from   sec s with (nolock)
    left join  suc WITH ( nolock) 
      on   s.cu = suc.cu
)
  intersect
    select s.*
    from   sec s with (nolock)
    join   hatch h1 with (nolock)
      on   h1.cu = s.cu
           join  port p1 WITH (nolock) 
             ON  h1.ic = p1.ic
            AND  p1.ptype = 'X'
```

i have seen the optimizer get stupid on those second level joins 
if so try

```
select s.*
from   sec s with (nolock)
join hact h1 WITH (nolock)
  on h1.cu = s.cu
  where h1.ic in (select ic from where ptype = 'X')
```

See my comment on deadlocks and with (nolock).
I don't consider with (nolock) a kludge and use it a lot.
If you are seeing a lot of deadlocks then you need to look at that.

Index cu, ic, and ptype.
Then test different versions of the query and look at the execution plan.
This is the type of query the query optimizer can have trouble with.
The query optimizer is based on statistics and can even change an execution plan.
You may need to include table hints for the joins.

Comment: Thanks Testing will let you know

Comment: You missed the difference in table names - `dport` and `port`

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking: (untested, hopefully maintains functional equivalence)

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.*
FROM   sec s
JOIN hact h WITH (nolock)
  ON s.cu = h.cu
LEFT JOIN dport p WITH (nolock)
  ON h.ic = p.ic
LEFT JOIN schanges c WITH (nolock)
  ON s.cu = c.cu
LEFT JOIN suk WITH (nolock)
  ON suk.cu = s.cu
JOIN port p2 WITH (nolock)
  ON h.ic = p2.ic 
WHERE p2.ptype = 'X' AND
  (p.ic IS NOT NULL OR c.cu IS NOT NULL OR suk.cu IS NOT NULL)
```

**Edit:** Added DISTINCT

Comment: This Query is not functionally equivalent

Comment: @Quantbuff I hope you tested it before saying that. Not having [a playground](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/) (or table structures) to play around with makes it difficult to find the problem.